# Xcode build fails in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cocoapods, cicd

I am using an Azure Devops Build pipeline CI to build my Xcode workspace. It is working fine on local and runs well on physical device. But I wanted to use the pipeline to automate the build process which gives me error:

```
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

The detailed error is, it is not able to load the contents of the file but that is not case when running on the xcode

```
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')


❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')
```

Here is the yaml file contents in pipeline:

```
trigger:
- A/B_testing

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ProjectName.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'ProjectName'
    xcodeVersion: '13'
    packageApp: false
    signingOption: 'default'
```

I have tried by removing the input and output files from Build Phase of the Xcode project, uninstall/install pods, have added the [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76929104/xcode-build-fails-in-azure-devops-pipeline) in Podfile, other solutions on SO but could not found anything relevant to my error. If someone have idea about this or had this issue before, kindly share.
Using Xcode 13.4 to build the app.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @MuhammadSarim not yet, may be an issue with the server. Does not found the actual reason and not available on internet too.

Comment: Try looking for all "error:" in azure logs you must find something that is causing this error. I have fixed my case and found some compile time error that my local compiler was not able to pick.

Comment: Same here, I am not getting any error on my local machine. This is from server side.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you need to add a 'CocoaPods@0' task before the Xcode build task to carry out a 'pod install' in the pipeline, can you try that?

Comment: I gave it a try but after that, it is giving an error like `no such module` for pod import files

Comment: It worked after specifying the workspace and scheme name. Do you know how to build pipeline for publishing the ipa to TestFlight/AppStore?